# Get List<T> by its generic type T from a collection (C#)

Tags: c#, list, generics, dictionary, collections

I have many `List`s containing objects of different types, but all those types have one common base class `ModelBase`. Each generic `List` type is unique i.e. there won't be two lists containing the same types.

In the end I want to have a function like `public List<TModel> GetModelList<TModel>()` that takes the type of any object derived from `ModelBase` either as generic type or as parameter and then returns the respective `List<TModel>` of that generic type.

What options do I have to achieve this?

I thought about a `Dictionary<Type, List<ModelBase>>` but then I have casts from the subclass types (e.g. `AreaModel`) to the base class type `ModelBase` for storing and the other way round when I fetch it again. I don't want to have to cast the lists each time before storing or after loading. Is there a way to simplify this? Maybe we could automate the cast, as we're passing the type of the `List` we want as argument?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply store the lists as an object in the internal dictionary, and cast to the specified type when required. No sense trying to store the lists as a list-of-modelbase since the lists are not of that type.

Something like this:

```
public class Container {    
    private readonly ConcurrentDictionary<Type, object> _container = 
        new ConcurrentDictionary<Type, object>();

    public List<TModel> Get<TModel>() where TModel: ModelBase {
        return _container.GetOrAdd(typeof(TModel), t => new List<TModel>()) as List<TModel>;        
    }
}
```

I'm using a concurrent dictionary to make sure only a single list instance is created for each type. You can easily add a method to store an existing list in the dictionary if you want.

```
// Usage
var container = new Container();
var person = container.Get<Person>();
var orders = container.Get<Order>();
```

Comment: From having a look at the MSDN, the ConcurrentDictionary is only relevant for thread-safety, but I don't really need that. Is there any other difference why you chose that instead of a normal Dictionary? I don't really understand what you mean with "make sure only a single list instance is created for each type" - that would be the same case with a normal dictionary as well, or not?

Comment: If I can make my own class thread-safe by something as simple as using a ConcurrentDictionary instead of a normal dictionary, then yes I will. And yes, if you use it only in a single-threaded environment then a normal dictionary will work fine, but you won't have the handy `.GetOrAdd(..)` method.

Answer (score 1):

What about

```
public List<Person> GetPersons()
{
     var table = context.ExecutDataTable();
     return GetModelList<Person>(table);
}

public List<T> GetModelList<T>(DataTable table) where T : ModelBase, new()
{        
    var list = new List<T>();
    foreach(DataRowView row in table.DefaultView)
    {
        var item = new T();
        t.Load(row);
        list.Add(item);
    }
    return list;
}
```

Or you can use `Cast` extension method. This solution makes sense if you have a method in your data layer that always returns a `List<ModelBase>` but you are sure your list only contains `Person` objects

```
public List<Person> GetPersonList()
{
    // returns a List<ModelBase>
    var persons = context.ExecuteList("SELECT * FROM person");
    return persons.Cast<Person>().ToList();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There are other ways to archive the result you want, you can create a static class:

```
static class Store<TModel> where TModel : ModelBase
{
    public static readonly List<TModel> List = new List<TModel>();
}
```

This way you have a list for each `Store<T>`.
Another way is using [Monostate Pattern](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?MonostatePattern):

```
class Store2<TModel> where TModel : ModelBase
{
    static readonly List<TModel> list = new List<TModel>();
    public List<TModel> List { get { return list; } }
}
```

Then you can use it like this:

```
var storeA = new Store<ModelA>();
storeA.List.Add(new ModelB());

var storeB = new Store<ModelB>();
storeB.List.Add(new ModelB());
```